Incorrect SHA-256 HMAC calculation in Golang
I'm trying to calculate the SHA-256 of a string with the following spec:


Construct a string by concatenating the string form of the sorted field name-value pairs. The string form of a name-value pair is the
name followed by the value.


The field name and the value in each field name-value pair are joined using "=" as the separator.
The resulting joined field name-value pairs are themselves joined using "&" as the separator.


Create a SHA-256 HMAC of the resultant string using the hex decoded value of your merchant secret as the key. The SHA-256 HMAC algorithm
is defined in Federal Information Processing Standard 180-2. We
strongly recommend that you use one of the numerous implementations
available in most programming languages.


On step 2, let's say the final string after concatenation is
user_SessionId=567890&vpc_AccessCode=75A6GH9&vpc_Amount=1000&vpc_CardExp=1305&vpc_CardNum=345678901234564&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_MerchTxnRef=txn1&vpc_Merchant=MastercardITESTMERCHANT&vpc_Version=1
Continue to step 3. Let's say our merchant secret key is BB48A64077A1CBF08FF0D91C5A9FE42B. Here's my code which performs the SHA-256 HMAC calculation:
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func HMAC256(input string, secret string) string {
    data := []byte(input)
    hmac := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(secret))
    hmac.Write([]byte(data))
    return hex.EncodeToString(hmac.Sum(nil))
}


func main() {
    signatureString := "user_SessionId=567890&vpc_AccessCode=75A6GH9&vpc_Amount=1000&vpc_CardExp=1305&vpc_CardNum=345678901234564&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_MerchTxnRef=txn1&vpc_Merchant=MastercardITESTMERCHANT&vpc_Version=1"
    MERCHANT_SECRET := "BB48A64077A1CBF08FF0D91C5A9FE42B"

    decodedByteArr, err := hex.DecodeString(MERCHANT_SECRET)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("HMAC-256 result: %s\n", HMAC256(signatureString, string(decodedByteArr)))

}

The output of my code is (tested on macOS 15.2 M2 with Go 1.23.4) : 9dba9f5c2d64fad4c6ef940c868a7cae0791ef6c796883e6da12f88cc008ebe4. Yet the spec says different: ffad3a7db59cf91963ac1e53aa08b97e878c498e13fcc1de0a20b9a8e0e3eff9
Which one is correct? I'm not a cryptography expert, so any help is appreciated.

Can you provide a link to the spec you're following? Are you certain you're building the string correctly in step 2? Does the spec provide either a worked example or sample code?

Your code seems correct given your inputs; we can verify that by performing the same operation on the command line with openssl. Running echo -n 'user_SessionId=567890&vpc_AccessCode=75A6GH9&vpc_Amount=1000&vpc_CardExp=1305&vpc_CardNum=345678901234564&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_MerchTxnRef=txn1&vpc_Merchant=MastercardITESTMERCHANT&vpc_Version=1' | openssl sha256 -hmac $(xxd -r -p <<<"BB48A64077A1CBF08FF0D91C5A9FE42B") produces the same value (9dba9f5c2d64fad4c6ef940c868a7cae0791ef6c796883e6da12f88cc008ebe4).

@larsks I copy pasted the example directly from Mastercard's "Virtual Payment Client Reference Guide". Check page 122 (SHA-256 HMAC Calculation) on this PDF: https://www.commbank.com.au/content/dam/commbank-assets/business/merchants/2022-06/commweb-1.0-reference-guide.pdf

@anta40: there is obviously an error in this documentation - see my answer.

Your code is correct. It looks instead like an error in the documentation you use (like the one found here). If the substring "Mastercard" in signatureString is changed to "MasterCard" (upper case "C" instead of lower case) then one gets the expected HMAC as result.
